# Automating 6 Keypresses (DreamWeaver Save Upload Page Refresh and Back) into 1 Keypress with AutoHotKey

Tags: web, keyboard-shortcuts, workflow, autohotkey

While designing my website I'm using often the following combination of key presses:

- In DreamWeaver I press `Ctr+S` to save and upload the current page to the server
- Then I must wait a second for the FTP to finish uploading the page to the server
- Then I press `Alt+Tab` to switch from DreamWeaver to my Chrome browser
- Then I press `Ctr+F5` to force a complete refresh

I would like to replace these **6** keypresses in just **1** key press, for example let's say the `Caps` key.

I would then like to press `Caps` (or another key) once more to function as a `Alt+Tab` bringing me back to Dreamweaver (and also as a way to deactivate caps lock).

I have made something which, though elegant, does not work.

```
^Caps::
Send, Ctr+S
Wait, 1000ms
Send, Alt+Tab
Send, Ctrl+F5
return
```

What code needs to be fed in to AutoHotKey to achieve the above steps?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CapsLock::
    Send,   ^S
    Sleep,  1000
    Send,   {LAlt Down}{Tab}{LAlt Up}
    Send    ^{F5}
    Send,   {LAlt Down}{Tab}{LAlt Up}
return
```

This wont change capslock state.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work! I saved your solution in an .ahk file and ran it, but in DreamWeaver nothing happens when I press the Capslock button. I see the keyboard Caps LED goes on/off, but nothing happens, the page is not saved or alt tabbed. Nothing.. But, when I try the same in a different program like a notepad editor and press caps the screen is alt tabbed and refreshed!? Is DreamWeaver somehow allergic for AutoHotKey commands?

Comment: Have you tried to change the hotkey? Maybe is something related to the capslock while in dreamweaver. You may try ^CapsLok(Left control + capslock)

Comment: Good point!  `^CapsLok::` results in Error: Invalid Hotkey!  Ah I see a spellingmistake you mean `^CapsLock::`  That too does nothing. I even tried `^j::` (Ctr+J)  which is a key that is not bound to anything in my DreamWeaver, does nothing when I run the code. Even when I'm in other programs than DreamWeaver, for example in Chrome, then I do not see the dialog box for "Save as" which I do see when I manually press `Ctr+S`.

Comment: Both single keypress batch files with just  `CapsLock::`  or just `j::` brings up the "Save as" dialogbox nicely in Notepad, but NOT in DreamWeaver and also NOT in Chrome.

Comment: Try this, so we will know if its blocking the hotkey, or just the commands.
If the msgbox appears, we can use another way to make this work.

Add a "msgbox  test" without quotes inside the call.